# unable to delete service reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, tfs, service-reference

I've a **silverlight** project in visual studio under **TFS**. I was deleting its service reference, VS got hanged and when i restart VS, it's service reference was still there. Now when I try to delete it again, I'm getting this message

```
This operation cannot be completed. 
You are attempting to remove or delete a source-controlled item where the item is either exclusively locked elsewhere or otherwise unable to be deleted from source control.
```

It neither allow me to add any other reference with same name nor to update/ configure existing one.

when I try to update existing service reference, I'm getting this message

```
This operation cannot be completed. No such interface supported.
```

I'm totally stuck over here. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried going back to the last working state using TFS?

Comment: yes I tried it. but issue is still there.